# Solving an equation with multiple Modulus

Tags: equation-solving

I read a lot of posts solving equations with one Mod, but what happens when we have lets say a nested Mod equation like :

```
505= 500 + ((x % 66) % 9)
```

Is this equation solvable my Mathematica?
Can someone explain how to solve for x if possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Something mod 2 is maximally 2, it cannot become 500. Do you have an example where a solution actually exists?

Comment: My apologies. i just put numbers out of my head. fixed to solvable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This equation is immediately solvable by [`Reduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce.html):

```
ClearAll[x];
Reduce[505 == 500 + Mod[Mod[x, 66], 9], x, Integers]
(* Element[C[1], Integers] && (x == 5 + 66*C[1] || x == 14 + 66*C[1] || 
   x == 23 + 66*C[1] || x == 32 + 66*C[1] || x == 41 + 66*C[1] || 
   x == 50 + 66*C[1] || x == 59 + 66*C[1]) *)
```

Comment: thank you. Easier than i thought.